# How to get sub property value from ng-repeat using a firebaseArray?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I want to get the selected value from ng-repeat using the firebaseArray loaded, retrieving the value of profile.name

.json

```
profile: {
  name: 'default',
  description: 'default',
  permissions: {
    regUser: false,
    regProfile: false,
    regCustomer: false
  }
}
```

.html

```
<select class="form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="profile in vm.profiles" ng-model="vm.firebaseUser.profile">{{profile.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

.js

```
vm.createApplicationUser = function() {
            var profilesRef = firebase.database().ref('application/profiles/name/');
            vm.profiles = $firebaseArray(profilesRef);
            var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('application/users/').push().set({
                displayName: vm.firebaseUser.displayName,
                email: vm.firebaseUser.email,
                role: vm.firebaseUser.role,
                profile: vm.firebaseUser.profile
            });
        };
```

error

```
Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'application.users.-KL3BQ-F5a-HLa32an-R.profile'
    at Error (native)
    at Bf (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:340:67)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:341:166
    at Cb (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:259:627)
    at Bf (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:340:424)
    at Af (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:339:682)
    at U.g.set (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:467:241)
    at AdminCtrl.vm.createApplicationUser (http://localhost:3000/src/client/app/admin/admin.js:28:81)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14605:15), <anonymous>:4:271)
    at expensiveCheckFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15694:18)
```

Comment: didnt get what you want. What exactly is your problem? Do you only want to display the value on the select menu? why are you calling this push.set in the same method you populate the select?

Comment: The selected value on the 'select' html element is the value for a field on my firebase set function (profile: vm.firebaseUser.profile). I want to save on this property only the name of profile like I show on html ({{profile.name}}). The push function generates a random key for the new entry in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-model should be in `<select>` tag and not in `<option>`.